# Shoot bullet in the Direction the Ship is Facing Swift and Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I am making a space shooter game, and I would like the ship to be able to fire bullets in the direction it is facing. I have figured out how to make the bullet rotate in the direction of the ship, but I haven't gotten it to shoot in the right direction. At the moment, I only shoot up. I have a screen shot down below. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
if shootButton.containsPoint(location) {

            let Bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BulletGalaga.png")
            Bullet.zPosition = -5

            Bullet.position = CGPointMake(ship.position.x, ship.position.y)
            Bullet.zRotation = ship.zRotation
            Bullet.zPosition = ship.zPosition

            let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 0.8)
            //let action = SKAction.moveTo(self.ship.size.height, duration: 0.8)
            let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            Bullet.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

            Bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Bullet.size)
            Bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            Bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            self.addChild(Bullet)

        }
```

Thanks.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXiI6.png)

Comment: I've tried to replace the let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 0.8) With just moveTo, but it didn't work. I know I somehow need it to say that the bullet has to move in the direction of the ships zPosition... I also know that the moveToY has to be changed. Any ideas? @CleverError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the zPosition? you mean zRotation.  and that will only calculate the angle that the bullet draws,  you need to do some trig to figure out where the bullet will go to in a straight line:

PSEUDO CODE:

```
let action = SKAction.moveTo(
               CGPointMake(
                            travelDistance * cos(Bullet.zRotation) + Bullet.position.x,
                            travelDistance * sin(Bullet.zRotation) + Bullet.position.y
               ), 
               duration: 0.8)
```

Comment: I get the error "use of unresolved identifier tavelDistance"

Comment: Yes, you can't copy my code verbatum, you need to figure out how far you want the bullet to travel

Comment: the entire thing doesn't work. Is there a way for you to rewrite it? Lot's of errors... could you possibly fix it?

Comment: You are going to have to do some work here,  I don't have all the functions memorized to Cast to the correct types

Comment: I've edited it down to this, but it says there is an extra argument. let action = SKAction.moveTo(30 * cos(Bullet.zRotation),(30 * -sin(Bullet.zRotation)), duration: 0.8)

Comment: you don't have the CGPointMake

Comment: it's moving in different direction now, but not in the direction of the ship. It's also going really really slow

Comment: well first, do not calculate it every frame, second which way is it going, third you are only moving 30 points in almost a second,  yes that is slow

Comment: It's weird.. sometimes it's going the right way, and sometimes it's as much as 90 degrees off

Comment: when your zRotation is at 0, which way is the ship facing

Comment: to the left?  your tip points to the left?  that can't  be right

Comment: why is your screen space backwards

Comment: It's landscape. Can you edit the code to work for it?

Comment: landscape doesn't make it backwards,  your point at (0,0) should be the bottom left of the screen,  I need to know why it is the bottom right

Comment: not until we figure out what is wrong with your screen coordinates, otherwise things may get jacked up

Comment: it'll be ok... Ill cross that bridge when I get to it.... Just help me fix it like this... please. 0,0 is right in the middle

Comment: you don't understand, this is part of the problem, because you are telling me it is pointing left, how do I know you have it set up correctly.  Maybe you are holding the phone upside down, maybe you are in portrait mode and you think you are in landscape, maybe the point at (0,0) doesn't exist in your weird world,  you need to think about these things before we can apply the trig

Comment: if (0,0) is in the middle, then where is (10,10)?

Comment: I have plenty of trig already and it works fine. 10,10 is to the right of the middle... which makes sense

Comment: if 10,10 is to the right, then your texture on your ship is wrong,  that means the ship has to move in a negative direction to move forward

Comment: I GOT IT! I had to make both the cos and the sin negative... Look at the updated answer

Comment: You should't edit other peoples answers,  the point of stack overflow is to have other people with the same problem get an answer without having to ask a new question,  my answer supports those folks out there,  don't know why you have a bizarro world set up, but for others it will work as the answer states.  Plus, constant numbers?  bad

Answer (score -1):

```
let action = SKAction.moveTo(
                CGPointMake(
                    400 * -cos(Bullet.zRotation - 1.57079633) + Bullet.position.x,
                    400 * -sin(Bullet.zRotation - 1.57079633) + Bullet.position.y
                ),
                duration: 0.8)
```

Comment: M_PI_2 if you want 1/2 PI

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.