# Swift3 SpriteKit: Shooting bullets at angles

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit

Currently my app has an enemy that shoots a bullet which travels from the enemy at whatever x and y position it may be towards the bottom of the screen - the size of the bullet. This is an SKAction that happens only once in the enemy trajectory from top to bottom and this trajectories are all at random X positions.

What I want to do is to shoot 4 bullets, at 4 different angles. 45, 135, 225 and 270 degrees.

Currently my fireBullet function is as follows:

```
func fireBullet() {
    let bullet = EnemyBullet(imageName: bulletImage, bulletSound: bulletSound)
    bullet.name = "Bullet"
    bullet.setScale(1)
    bullet.position = CGPoint(x: enemy.position.x, y: enemy.position.y - bullet.size.height)
    bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: bullet.size)
    bullet.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.enemy
    bullet.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
    bullet.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.player
    gameScene.addChild(bullet)

    let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: -gameScene.size.height * 0.1, duration: bulletTimeInScreen)
    let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet, deleteBullet])
    bullet.run(bulletSequence)
}
```

I'm assuming that I can change bullet for bullet1 and repeat for bullet2, 3 and 4. With that I can probably use zRotation to rotate each bullet to that specific angle.

What I can not figure out is in which direction to move the bullet. Specifically, how to figure out the X and Y of the SKAction.moveTo from the enemy's position at the time.

I have searched and read many articles but none that can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You want to learn how atan2 works, basically you want to convert Rect Coordinates to Polar coordinates

Comment: @JoseCarrillo I would recommend you read this excellent tutorial on raywenderlich.com https://www.raywenderlich.com/57368/trigonometry-game-programming-sprite-kit-version-part-1

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do it thanks to this post [Shoot bullet in the Direction the Ship is Facing Swift and Sprite Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784784/shoot-bullet-in-the-direction-the-ship-is-facing-swift-and-sprite-kit) by KnightOfDragon which by the way, pointed me in the right direction with trigonometry.

Basically I changed the variable name from bullet to bullet1 and added bullet2, 3 and 4 changing the zRotation within the same function. The moveBullet1 SKAction fires the bullet in the direction the zRotation points at.

The degrees use the extension shown below. I can't remember where in this site I found that one.

```
func fireBullet() {
    let bullet1 = EnemyBullet(imageName: bulletImage, bulletSound: bulletSound)
    bullet1.name = "Bullet"
    bullet1.setScale(scale)
    bullet1.position = CGPoint(x: enemy.position.x, y: enemy.position.y)
    bullet1.zRotation = CGFloat(45.degreesToRadians)
    bullet1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: bullet1.size)
    bullet1.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.enemy
    bullet1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
    bullet1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.player
    gameScene.addChild(bullet1)

    let moveBullet1 = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(
        x: distance * cos(bullet1.zRotation) + bullet1.position.x,
        y: distance * sin(bullet1.zRotation) + bullet1.position.y),
        duration: bulletTimeInScreen)
    let deleteBullet1 = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    let bullet1Sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet1, deleteBullet1])

    bullet1.run(bullet1Sequence)
}


extension Int {
    var degreesToRadians: Double { return Double(self) * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Double { return Double(self) * 180 / .pi }
}
```

[image: Four bullets shot in different directions.]